# Using ActiveCell value to compare with the result of activecell formula value VBA

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup

I am trying to look at the value of an ActiveCell (say cell F3), run a vlookup within the same cell (F3) and see if the value of that vlookup matches the value of the activecell (F3).

This is an example of the Excel sheet:
[image]

Here is my code:

```vb
Sub Grade_comment_Updated2()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastcolumn = Cells(2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column 
'Fills to last column. Last column is defined by last column of row 2 that has data in it'

ActiveSheet.Cells(3, 6).Select 
Do Until ActiveCell.Column = lastcolumn + 1  
    If ActiveCell.Value <> ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 
    "=VLOOKUP(R[-3]C,C1:C4,4,0)".Value Then
        ActiveCell.ClearNotes
            ActiveCell.AddCommentThreaded ("Was " & ActiveCell.Value)
                Activecell.value = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 
                "=VLOOKUP(R[-3]C,C1:C4,4,0)".Value
                    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    ElseIf ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = 
    "=IFNA(VLOOKUP(R[-3]C,C1:C4,4,0),R[-1]C)".Value Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
End If
Loop
'Looks in to cell F3 (This currently has a letter assigned to it), then runs a vlookup in the same cell (F3) to see if the letter matches the same letter that the vlookup is checking, if the letter is different then replace it with the different letter and put a comment saying what the previous letter was, then go to next cell to the right and repeat'

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox "Grade Update Complete"
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Please *indent* your code when posting, or it's much harder to read.

Answer (score 0):

`Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup` is needed to run the vlookup within the cell via VBA and compare against the current cell character.

`On Error Resume Next` is used to pick up any vlookup errors where the lookup value does not exist in the range. (IFERROR/IFNA cannot be used via the `application.worksheetfunction.vlookup` method; so it's an alternative form of error handling in this instance):

```vb
Sub Grade_comment_Updated2()

Dim x As String
 
Range("F3").Select

Do

    On Error Resume Next
 
    If ActiveCell.Value = "" Then
        ActiveCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0).Value, ActiveSheet.Range("A:D"), 4, False)
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
    Else
        If x = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0).Value, ActiveSheet.Range("A:D"), 4, False) = ActiveCell Then
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
        Else
            If x = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0).Value, ActiveSheet.Range("A:D"), 4, False) <> ActiveCell Then
                ActiveCell.ClearNotes
                ActiveCell.AddCommentThreaded ("Was " & ActiveCell.Value)
                ActiveCell = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0).Value, ActiveSheet.Range("A:D"), 4, False)
                ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Activate
            End If
        End If
    End If
 
Loop Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell.Offset(-2, 0).Value)
 
End Sub
```

[image]